# Do I have to use the same vlan number for a sub-internface name in a Cisco router?

Tags: networking, vlan, interface

When creating a sub-interface for use with dot1q encapsulation. Do I have to match the name of the interface with the vlan number?

For example:

```
int g1/0/0.40
encap dot1q 40
```

or would this also work?

```
int g1/0/0.50
encap dot1q 40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to match the name of the
>   interface with the vlan number?

No, I don't believe so. It's just a standard convention (and one I'd highly recommend sticking to) to reduce confusion when reading or modifying the config.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking does the VLAN ID need to have anything to do with the IP range? If so then not at all, VLANs are a layer 2 function, they don't care about IP at all.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with ErikA, it keeps it easy to remember what sub-interface is mapped to what vlan.  In some cases, sub-interfaces, vlans, and hsrp groups can use the same number to keep track of them all.